# Periodic batch notifications on iPhone

Tags: iphone, notifications

I wanted to ask if it is possible to have periodic batch notifications on iPhone?

It's annoying to be distracted by every notification but I would be fine with getting a notification every hour or two with a summary of the notifications that popped up in the meantime.

If I turn off the notifications I usually don't check my phone so frequently so the extra reminder is useful for me.

Is there such a feature or is there an app that can do this?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment this is currently impossible. The only way I can think of is using Airplane Mode to stop pretty much all notifications (and internet + phone + text as well) and turning it on whenever you want to receive notifications. When you turn Airplane Mode off all of the notifications will come flooding in. You could even set a timer to remind you every hour to turn off Airplane Mode. This isn't the most convenient method, and it doesn't block local notifications (not used very much) but this is currently the best way I know.

If you would like a better way to be integrated into iOS, leave Apple feedback at http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html, and maybe next year this could be in iOS 10.